# Unable to Click a row and call javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to trigger `$(this).toggleClass('selected');` for content table. When I debug it just skip this event. How can I make sure its being selected?

```
$('#contentChangesTable tr')
    .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
    .addClass('selected')
    .end()
    .click(function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).attr('checked', function () {
                return !this.checked;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, HTML Please...

Comment: Is the code above in a $(document).ready() function?

Comment: Yes it is in a $(document).ready() function

Comment: are you just trying to change the selected class of the row, or are you also trying to check the checkbox on the row with a row click?

Comment: @tleish: The code does the latter (toggles checkbox by clicking row). The problem was using `attr` to set a `checkbox` checked value (which does not work).

Comment: The main issue When I debugged,the code is skipping after .click(function (event) { and its not going in to $(this).toggleClass('selected');

Comment: i'm trying to check the checkbox on the row with a row click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `prop` and not `attr` to set checked

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/RV46q/

```
$(function () {
    $('#contentChangesTable tr')
        .filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)')
        .addClass('selected')
        .end()
        .click(function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', function () {
                return !this.checked;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When I debugged,the code is skipping after .click(function (event) { and its not going in to $(this).toggleClass('selected');

Comment: I need to execute for it to pull the data

Comment: @user2807977: please update the JSFiddle I provided with your real HTML as *it* works but *yours* does not :)

Comment: I added a table and the detail jquery for the check box

Comment: <table>

<tr class="even">
<td class=" centered">
<input type="checkbox" value="undefined" name="selectedChanges">
</td>
<td class="sorting_1">NEW</td>
<td class=" ">1401297831778</td>
<td class=" ">SORTFOLDER</td>
<td class=" ">comcast.comMENU0000000000157121</td>
<td class=" ">
</td>
<td class=" ">38Th Floor Test</td>
<td class=" "></td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>

Comment: That HTML was invalid (as was `$function`). Start with this one and let me know what you want it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/RV46q/4/

Comment: and when click on the checkbox be able to schedule the data using ajax

Comment: Okay. Here's the problem: My answer, above, answers *the question you asked* (as it had only one problem). What you have is other problems that relate to code we have not seen. You need to provide a complete example of what you want and what you have already. I would suggest starting a new question, with a JSFiddle containing enough of the problem so it can be solved. The last example I gave you has no compile errors and valid HTML, so is a good place to start. Use that to build a new question with your real problem (not what you thought the problem was). Cheers